# Vertical Menu Submenu CSS Alignment

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, alignment

I have a vertical menu and need a submenu to pop out. I've got everything working except my sub menu doesn't align where it should horizontally. Instead, it jumps up against the header div above. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML

```
<div class="leftcontainer">
<ul>
  <li><a class="current" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Packaging</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Item</a></li> 
       <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>  
   </ul>
 </li>  
<li><a href="#">Transportation</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>  
   </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Warehousing</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Real Estate</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>

</ul>
```

CSS

```
.container {
          width: 960px;
          height:740px;
          margin-top: 0px;
          margin-right: auto;
          margin-bottom: 0px;
          margin-left: auto;
          padding-bottom: 10px;
          position: relative;
          overflow: auto;
          box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
      }

      body {
          font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
          background-image: url(../img/body-bg);
          background-repeat: repeat-x;
      }

      .leftcontainer {
          float: left;
          width: 160px;
          height: 650px;
          display: inline-block;
          background-image: url(../img/nav-div-bg.png);
          background-repeat: repeat-y;
          margin-bottom: 0px;
          clear: both;
          position: absolute;
          z-index: 999;
      }

      ul li {
          text-decoration: none;
          list-style-type: none;
          margin-left: -40px;
          text-align: left;
          display: block;
      }

      ul {
          margin-top:0px;
          margin-bottom: 0px;
          list-style-type: none;
      }

      ul li a:link {
          text-decoration: none;
          list-style-type: none;
          color: #FFF;
          display: block;
          padding-top: 20px;
          padding-bottom: 20px;
          padding-left: 20px;
          font-size: 16px;
      }

      ul li a:hover {
          text-decoration: none;
          list-style-type: none;
          color: #FFF;
          padding-left: 20px;
          display: block;
          padding-top: 20px;
          padding-bottom: 20px;
          background-image: url(../img/nav-bg.png);
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-position: left center;
          box-shadow: -30px 0px 9px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
      }

      .container ul li a:visited {
          text-decoration: none;
          list-style-type: none;
          color: #FFF;
          padding-left: 20px;
          display: block;
          padding-top: 20px;
          padding-bottom: 20px;
      }

      ul li ul {
          position: absolute;
          display: none;
          background: #5f6975;
          border-radius: 0px;
          padding-top: 0;
          padding-right: 0;
          padding-bottom: 0;
          padding-left: 0;
      }

      ul li:hover ul {
          display: inline-block;
          z-index: -1;
          left: 172px;
          top: 0px; 
      }

      ul ul li {
          background: #5f6975;
          float: none; 
          padding-left: 0px;
          border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
          border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
      }

      ul ul li a:link{
          padding: 10px 0px 10px 30px;
          color: #fff;
          width: 130px;
      } 

      ul ul li a:hover {
          background: #4b545f;
          box-shadow: none;
      }

      .current{
          text-decoration: none;
          list-style-type: none;
          color: #FFF;
          padding-left: 20px;
          display: block;
          padding-top: 20px;
          padding-bottom: 20px;
          background-image: url(../img/nav-bg.png);
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-position: left center;
          box-shadow: -30px 0px 9px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sub menu's should be positioned absolute. And for the positioning to work correct, you would need to position the parent `li` relative, so it acts as a reference for the absolute positioned child.

The minimum css would look something like this:

```
nav ul {
    float: left;
}
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}
nav ul li {
    position: relative;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}
```

and a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bp48q/

Note that this code will allow you to keep nesting sub menu's (which would be a ux nightmare, but that's a different story) and should keep working fine.

Comment: nav ul li position relative was the key. danke

Answer (score 0):

You should add `position: relative;` to the parent `<li>`.

Answer (score 0):

change `ul li ul` to `position: relative;` rather than `position: absolute;`

[This should do the trick](http://jsfiddle.net/3aqDD/)

Comment: position relative keeps the sub menu's in the flow, and therefore pushes the other content away (look at the main items beneath the active sub menu in your fiddle), which is very strange and probably not desired. I think sub menu's should always be positioned absolute to lift them out of the flow and prevent them from influencing the rest of the content.